# Make onClick button overlap content with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, z-index

So I need some help with overlapping content on page when a button is being pressed. Right now I have a function for an active button which helps me with opening a div(div panel) and closing it. I just want to know how you would go about making this div panel stetch across the page, when the button is being pressed.

I made it work with the overlap with a function by making my container active but I realised that it was completely wrong and had to change it. So right now (as I said before) I have active buttons.

Try to make it work through my current function with the buttonS, but nothing really changed. Maybe some z-index? Check the code out.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**Here's the code:**

```js
<!--Accordion script-->


var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {

    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}


//active container overlap
$('button').click(function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

})



//onClose function and refresh function


//var inFormOrLink;
//$('a').on('click', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });
//$('form').on('submit', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });

//$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
//return inFormOrLink ? "Do you really want to close?" : null; 
//})
```

```css
body {
  width: 100% margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 45%;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 27%;
  background-color: #FAF3E9;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/*Del 1*/

.d1knapp button {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 70%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.nextstep button {
  background-color: #EE7024;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 16.5%;
}


/*Del 1 slut*/


/*Del 2*/

.box {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: large;
  color: #17202A;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-left: 11%;
  margin-top: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#datum {
  width: 80%;
  margin: -2% 11%;
}

.datumStart {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1px;
}

.datumSlut {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 35%;
}

.skapa button {
  background-color: #EE7024;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 5%;
}


/*Del 2 slut*/


/* Del 3 */

button.accordion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

button,
.accordion h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #FAF3E9;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 700px;
}

.container div.active {
  height: 91%;
  margin-top: 9%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: #FAF3E9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#savechanges button {
  background-color: #EE7024;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 45%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 16.5%;
  position: fixed;
}

#addfiles button {
  background-color: #158F49;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 16.5%;
}


/* Del 3 slut */


/* Media del 1 */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 7% 11%;
  }
  /* Del 1 */
  .d1knapp button {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 6%;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nextstep button {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 17%;
  }
  /* Del 1 slut */
  /* Del 2 */
  #datum {
    float: left;
  }
  .skapa button {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10%;
  }
  /* Del 2 slut */
  /* Del 3 */
  /* Del 3 slut */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div id="header">

    <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
    <!--<span style="color: blue; float: right; text-decoration: underline; text-align: center; margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 0.5%; font-family:Arial,serif;"><h3>English</h3></span>-->

  </div>


  <div class="dokumentation">
    <button class="accordion"><h3>Dokumentation</h3>   </button>

    <div class="panel">

      <h1> hej </h1>

      <div id="addfiles">
        <button><h2>Lägg till nya filer</h2></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rättigheter">
    <button class="accordion"><h3>Rättigheter</h3>   </button>

    <div class="panel">

      <h1> hej </h1>

      <div id="addfiles">
        <button><h2>Lägg till nya filer</h2></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="aktiviteter">
    <button class="accordion"><h3>Aktiviteter</h3>   </button>

    <div class="panel">

      <h1> hej </h1>

      <div id="addfiles">
        <button><h2>Lägg till nya filer</h2></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="savechanges">


    <button><h2>Spara ändringarna</h2></button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have an error in your css, please change body to this:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Next, Change your container class to this:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2%;
  background-color: #FAF3E9;
}
```

By setting width:100% each element takes up the entire width of it's parent. So setting the width to 100% for body and container should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Wasn't quite the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer stated, you have an error in the definition of the body style. There is a ; missing after width: 100%;

As for your question, you could solve your problem by adding position: absolute to your panels, like so:

```
div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: #FAF3E9;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
}
```

You also need to remove the max-height:0 property, to allow the div to expand to the maximum height.
Adding box-sizing: border-box; prevents the panel from adding margings or paddings to the 100% width and in so becoming bigger than their parents.

Also, adding width and height of 100% to your panels when active, makes them fill up the page:

```
div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! That sort of solved the problem only problem is that whenever I push these buttons, I want a whole new div to pop up and cover up the rest of the content. So with other words if I was to push the "Rättigheter" button, the div.panel would pop up and cover the rest of the content and display what's in the div.panel.

Comment: Take my current code(don't change the css), and in the script where the active container overlap is change "button" to ".container div" to get a better understanding of how I want it. The only problem with this is that, when the div.panel displays, the entire container is active and I only want my buttons to be active when div.panel is displayed.